# Add extra columns with default values from a list in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like

df = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]}

Now i want the data frame to have additional columns from a list=['a','b','c'] with default values as 0.

so the output will be

```
Name  Age a b c
Tome  20  0 0 0
nick  21  0 0 0
krish 19  0 0 0
Jack  18  0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use variable `list`, because `builtin` (python code word).

For new columns is possible create dictionary from `list` and pass to [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
d = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

L = ['a','b','c'] 

df1 = df.assign(**dict.fromkeys(L, 0))
```

Or create new `DataFrame` and use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(0, columns=L, index=df.index))
```

---

```
print (df1)
    Name  Age  a  b  c
0    Tom   20  0  0  0
1   nick   21  0  0  0
2  krish   19  0  0  0
3   jack   18  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
>>> df.join(df.reindex(columns=list('abc'), fill_value=0))
    Name  Age  a  b  c
0    Tom   20  0  0  0
1   nick   21  0  0  0
2  krish   19  0  0  0
3   jack   18  0  0  0
```

You can also use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to create new df with `fill_value` zero. and than combine columns by using [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join).